# Unique matching in a bipartite graph

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, combinations, matching-theory

Let $K_{n,m}$ (m> n) have vertex set $ (V_i: i \in [n])$ and $ (W_i: i \in [m])$. Let f(n) be the number of distinct maximum matchings M in $K_{n,m}$ such that $V_iW_i$ is not in M for any $i \in [n]$

Describe f(n) using the principle of inclusion and exclusion. (So your final answer will be a sum).

I was thinking about using combinatorics but the question is specifically asking for principle of inclusion and exclusion and I am not sure how to invoke that here. Thank you

Comment: There are two things which would greatly improve the question. Firstly, make it clear what the source of the exercise is. Secondly, you could expand on your thoughts. Inclusion/exclusion *is* combinatorics, so the distinction you make is confusing. If you show the approach that you would consider natural, it's possible that an answer would be as simple as "That's what they wanted".

Comment: @peter taylor hi Peter, this is for my undergraduate graph theory class. We havent used combinatorics in the class. So I was thinking of mapping it to some matching etc. Thank you!

Comment: Can you count the number of maximum matchings where you ignore the $V_iW_i$ condition? How about the number of matchings where $V_1$ is matched with $W_1$? Take all the matchings, subtract out the bad ones, add back in the doubly subtracted matchings, etc.

Comment: @MikeEarnest thanks Mike, I solved the problem myself. I'll post a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total number of maximum matchings is: $\frac{m!}{(m-n)!}$ in a bipartite graph with m and n vertices. Then by the inclusion and exclusion principle (substracting the number of unwanted cases):

M = $ \frac{m!}{(m-n)!}$ - $ {n \choose 1} \frac{(m-1)!}{(m-n)!} $+$ n \choose 2 $
 $ \frac{(m-2)!}{(m-n)!} $ + ... - $n \choose n$ $\frac{(m-n)!}{(m-n)!} $ or more concisely:

= $ \sum_{i=0}^n $ $ (-1)^i $ $ n \choose i $ $ \frac{(m-i)!}{(m-n)!} $